# Overstayed Student Visa for 2 years in Canada, almost 8years ago

Tags: canada, overstaying, visa-refusals

I overstayed my student visa in Canada for almost 2 years..that was almost 8 years ago I voluntarily left after my overstay and after moving back I have a full time job etc. here now..I want to get a visitor visa this year to visit friends in Canada, will I face any problems/rejections/bans when I apply..I have no intention on staying back and I want to just visit for 2 weeks any way I can make that clear to them? or Should I not even bother applying?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone here can offer anything but advice. What did the paperwork state when you voluntarily left? Were you banned?

Comment: I didn't receive any letter asking me to leave..I wasn't issued any deportation letter or anything of that sort..I just left voluntarily when I realized I was doing a stupid thing..Canada doesnt have exit controls so they dont really even bother looking at how long you stayed there etc.

Comment: So you have no proof that you overstayed? More importantly, *Canada* has none? hmm, if true, then who heard the tree fall in the forest?

Comment: They obviously can check records I think on airline and entry dates but they dont stamp your passport or have the forms like US, its not obvious if they dont check records I meant to say..I am just worried about it if I'm going to be banned or something then I would just avoid travelling there altogether..

Comment: I think your best chance is to ask for a visa, it is the best way to know if it is possible to go. What I mean is people who do not need a visa do not get to know if they will enter until they actually arrive at the border. 
And as you will also visit the US, if the border agent refuses you, you can still go back to the US and fly from the US to Paris.

Comment: Finding an airline record from this many years ago will be incredibly difficult if at all possible. For example, the EU http://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/may/25/us-to-store-passenger-data keeps PNRs for at most five years.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to depend almost entirely on **whether Canada knows you have overstayed**.  If they don't, you should be OK; if they do, you're very likely to get rejected.

In your shoes, I would just try my luck, and have a plan B in case you don't get the visa.  Note that *you will likely have to lie on the application*, both about overstaying in Canada (you don't want to say "Yes" to this) and about previous visits, although this could go both ways: it's risky to say you visited Canada before, and it's also risky to omit the visit.  My gut feel is that it's better to list your previous visit and give the dates your visa was granted for, but YMMV.

In any case, apply for the US & European visas first and book your flights to Paris from the US, not Canada.  This was, any Canadian rejection doesn't affect them.  You might also want to consider getting a new passport first, so the fact that you didn't leave Canada for two years is not obvious.

Comment: The application form is here: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5257E.pdf  And yes, you are asked about previous travel.

Comment: And you'll be banned (or not) because of the previous overstay, not because you apply.  But if you want to play it 100% safe, just don't visit Canada.